# MS-Access button is using fileModDate = f.DateLastModified;how do I compare the fileModDate to todays date

Tags: vba, ms-access

In this database there are buttons for each day of the week; user is required to click the button relating to the current day of the week and this executes some basic functions. I need to add in a contingency which makes the code look at the last modified date of the files that the button will look at and compare it to today's date. If the last modified date isn't today's date then I don't want the user to be able to execute the commands behind that button, and be forced to execute the correct button, which does actually relate to the current day of the week.

```
Private Sub Command19_Click()

    Dim FSO As Object

    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    Dim fileModDate As String

    Dim Response2 As Integer

    'To have a second message box, do I need to set another parameter here? I.E Dim Response3 As Integer (?)

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile("\\file_path\file_name.csv")

    fileModDate = f.DateLastModified

    Response2 = MsgBox(prompt:="Files are dated - " & fileModDate & ". Do you wish to Continue?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

    If Response2 = vbNo Then

        Exit Sub

    Else

        'I assume I need to compare fileModDate to current date here. IF this is today's date then continue, IF NOT, then prompt user with message, "Button date does not match today's date". Do not allow user to continue until they have clicked a button for which the fileModDate = today's date.

    End If

    FromPath = "\\file_path"
    ToPath = "\\file_path"

    MsgBox "Files Copied"

End Sub
```

I'm aware that this code won't look right in the post but as this is my first time posting here, I would appreciate if someone could point out my error. Also, I have searched the site for answers to this question and have not found an answer relating to this specific example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
    If Format(F.DateLastModified, "dd/mm/yyyy") <> Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
        MsgBox ("Button date does not match today's date")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Hi Thomas G,

Where would this piece of code be placed? 

In my sample code above, you can see where I assumed it would go; I've entered the following note - 

'I assume I need to compare fileModDate to current date here. IF this is today's date then continue, IF NOT, then prompt user with message, "Button date does not match today's date". Do not allow user to continue until they have clicked a button for which the fileModDate = today's date.

I've tested this, and nothing happens; I might be wrong in thinking this is where the piece of code needs to be inserted though.

Comment: Thomas G, I figured out where to put the code and it works a treat, thank you for your help! :)